# How to find the locations from where the word was selected as keyword by Microsoft text analytics APIi?

Tags: python, nlp, text-analysis, azure-cognitive-services

I am using Microsoft cognitive APIs for finding relevant keywords in my paragraph. I need to know from which sentences were those keywords were selected. Is there any way to do that because demo by Microsoft highlights the places from where that keyword was selected.

Answer (score 1):

I am from the team that develops the Text Analytics API.

Currently, we only return the key phrases found in the input document. These may occur multiple times in a given input document, which would also increase the likelihood that it is selected as a key phrase.

The demo shown on our website highlights any exact occurrence of a key phrase, which you could also do in your scenario.